# Pass id in onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have like this:
var array = ["name1","imagesrc1","name2",imagesrc2","name3","imagesrc3",...];

I print the images but I would like to recall a function that writes the name somewhere (or makes an alert with the name) when I click on the image.

My code is:

```
function RightTable(objecto,wrappercontent)
{
for(j=0;j<objecto.length;j++)
    {
        var div= document.createElement('div');
        var immagine = document.createElement('img');
        immagine.src= "http://www.mysite.com/png/public/card/" + objecto[j+1] + "?width=292";

        immagine.setAttribute('class', 'card');
        immagine.setAttribute('id' , objecto[j]);
        immagine.setAttribute('onClick', "alertID(*idoftheimage*));

        div.appendChild(immagine);
        wrappercontent.appendChild(div);

        j+1;

    }
}
```

How can I pass to alertID() the id of the image that is the name of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`immagine.setAttribute('onClick', "alertID(this.id)");`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for(j=0;j<objecto.length;j++)
{
  (function(j){
        var div= document.createElement('div');
        var immagine = document.createElement('img');
        immagine.src= "http://www.mysite.com/png/public/card/" + objecto[j+1] + "?width=292";

        immagine.setAttribute('class', 'card');
        immagine.setAttribute('id' , objecto[j]);
        immagine.setAttribute('onClick', "alertID(*idoftheimage*)");

        div.appendChild(immagine);
        wrappercontent.appendChild(div);

        j+1;

  })(j);
}
```