# Pass an id in javascript onClick button

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my onClick function inside the button tag

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info " onClick= "view('<?php echo $code ?>')" name="view" >View</button>
```

This my view function inside the .js file

```
function view(id){
    alert('id');
}
```

I am trying but id didn't pass to the function
Note that i also have include that file

Comment: check the generate HTML, Do you some argument to `view` function?

Comment: cannot write php code inside js file :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass id in onclick function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360155/pass-id-in-onclick-function)

Comment: you not share code for view function

Comment: Here it is, .js file code is updated

Comment: @ShubhamVerma      there is no duplication of id in the whole page

Answer (score 0):

Your alert echoes the **string** "id" not the value of the **variable** "id". You should remove the single quotes in the *view* function.

`function view(id) { alert(id); }`